# SVG height and width accuracy and border position

Tags: svg

I have two questions regarding svg:

1. I have the following rectangle

   ```
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100px" height="100px" style="fill:blue" />
   ```

   For some reason the width and height of the rectangle is not 100 px but 84px, why is that?
2. I want to add border to svg elements but I want the border to be inside the elements. I know that for html elements like div I can use the following styling:

   div{
           box-sizing:border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
       }

I tried to apply this to SVG elements and it didn't work, is there any other solution?

Comment: I think that the first one is not really a problem. Chrome's debugger displays 84px but the div wrapping the svg is 100px and they're both the same size so I guess it's a bug the debugger.

Comment: This is probably the fault of your viewbox declaration. What does your <svg> element look like?

Comment: Nothing special in the svg: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"></svg>. You can take a look at the following page: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_rect, just try to play with the stroke width and you'll see that the border is partialy on the rectange and partially on the outside and size of the rectangle changes when you enlarge the bordewr